# vbscript in HTML files not render in IE 11, Windows 7

Tags: vbscript

I have this simple vbscript code:

```
<script type="text/vbscript">document.write("hello world")</script>
```

However when I view this file in IE 11 on Windows 7 hello world is not displayed.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This might be the issue: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn384057(v=vs8.5).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As of Internet Explorer 11, VBScript is considered deprecated and should no longer be used as a scripting language for IE11. Webpages displayed in IE11 edge mode won't execute VBScript code.

More information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn384057(v=vs.85).aspx